# Using MestReNova: An Introduction

Tags: spectroscopy, nmr-spectroscopy

Can anyone help me with a quick question regarding MestReNova 9.0. I have been fiddling with this thing all day and before you ask yes, I have consulted the users guide to no avail.

I want to do three things:

1)Rescale the chemical shift axis to focus only on the relevant sections of my spectra.

2)Set a threshold so that only peaks above a certain intensity will automatically label.

3)how on earth do you get the parameter box to fit onto the page? Ive managed to get it up but it is about three times larger than my spectra and rescaling using the little green buttons leaves it the same size but just cuts loads out.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Testing this on version 9 will have to wait until tomorrow, but on version 8 (which I have in front of me, but which has limited differences to version 9 by memory)

1)Rescale the chemical shift axis to focus only on the relevant sections of my spectra.

Do a manual zoom.

->View >Zoom >Manual Zoom (or just type M, or click the manual zoom button)

Type in the values you want

2)Set a threshold so that only peaks above a certain intensity will automatically label.

Do Pick Picking via a Manual Threshold

->Analysis >Peak Picking >Manual Threshold (or just type K)

Left click and hold to define a box within which you will have your peaks picked

3)how on earth do you get the parameter box to fit onto the page? Ive managed to get it up but it is about three times larger than my spectra and rescaling using the little green buttons leaves it the same size but just cuts loads out.

You need to resize the text to a smaller font size

- First select the parameters box.
- Left click the parameters (which should have the green selected boxes shown) and choose properties. Make sure under the geometry tab, the Auto box is selected for size.
- Then from the text toolbar (by default is usually at the bottom of the screen, but if not shown go to >View>Toolbars>Text) change the font size to something small enough to fit on the screen.

Try that for your version - if no luck I'll check on one of my other processing stations tomorrow which has version 9 installed. Let me know how you go.

Comment: Brilliant answer thank you very much! It is slightly different but mostly what you say sounds exactly the same as the previous version. thanks again